# Simplificar código jquery función repetida

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hay algún modo de simplificar estas 3 funciones principales repetidas tantas veces en 3 funciones únicas ?

```js
jQuery(function () {
var $els = $('pre[id^=pictureY5]'),
    i = 0,
    len = $els.length;

$els.slice(1).hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
        i = (i + 1) % len
        $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
}, 300)
})
jQuery(function () {
var $els = $('pre[id^=pictureX2]'),
    i = 0,
    len = $els.length;

$els.slice(1).hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
        i = (i + 1) % len
        $els.eq(i).fadeIn(
   })
}, 200)
})
setInterval(function() {
    $('.outtime30').fadeOut(0);
}, 30000); 
setInterval(function() {
    $('.outtime34').fadeOut(0);
}, 34000);
setInterval(function() {
    $('.outtime40').fadeOut(0);
}, 40000);

$(function() {
  $(".intime2").delay(2000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime4").delay(4000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime5").delay(5000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime4").delay(4000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime5").delay(5000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime6").delay(6000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime8").delay(8000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime10").delay(10000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime12").delay(12000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime14").delay(14000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime15").delay(15000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime17").delay(17000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime20").delay(20000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime25").delay(25000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime27").delay(27000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime30").delay(30000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime35").delay(35000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime40").delay(40000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime45").delay(45000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime50").delay(50000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime55").delay(55000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime60").delay(60000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime70").delay(70000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime80").delay(80000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime90").delay(90000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime100").delay(100000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime110").delay(110000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime120").delay(120000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime140").delay(140000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime160").delay(160000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime180").delay(180000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime210").delay(210000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime240").delay(240000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime300").delay(300000).fadeIn(0);
});
```

```html
    <div class="adin adsbg intime14 fixed top outtime34" style="right:0;">
    <pre id="pictureW2" class="fontcolor fontmid1">
    </pre>
    <pre id="pictureW22" class="fontcolor fontmid1">
    </pre>
      </div>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes control sobre el HTML?

Comment: No @alvaromontoro tengo que hacerlo desde javascript

Comment: ¿No puedes añadir clases ni atributos ni nada por el estilo?

Comment: No @AlvaroMontoro es un html prácticamente infinito y no puedo me permiten meterme a modificarlo ahora mismo.

Comment: Y lo que quieres simplificar son las dos primeras funciones, la parte con los intimes y ¿los outtimes también?¿Podrías añadir un ejemplo característico de cada elemento HTML?

Comment: Hecho, quiero simplificar las funciones intime por un lado; outtime por otro y la del pre id por otro @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: Ok. Preparando una respuesta. Quizás no la mejor, pero creo que funcionará

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos a ir una a una, viendo las partes que quieres simplificar:

**1. Intime**

Empiezo con este porque es más "sencillo" y es más grande. Éste es tu código:

```
$(function() {
  $(".intime2").delay(2000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime4").delay(4000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime5").delay(5000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime4").delay(4000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime5").delay(5000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime6").delay(6000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime8").delay(8000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime10").delay(10000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime12").delay(12000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime14").delay(14000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime15").delay(15000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime17").delay(17000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime20").delay(20000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime25").delay(25000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime27").delay(27000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime30").delay(30000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime35").delay(35000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime40").delay(40000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime45").delay(45000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime50").delay(50000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime55").delay(55000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime60").delay(60000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime70").delay(70000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime80").delay(80000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime90").delay(90000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime100").delay(100000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime110").delay(110000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime120").delay(120000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime140").delay(140000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime160").delay(160000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime180").delay(180000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime210").delay(210000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime240").delay(240000).fadeIn(0);
  $(".intime300").delay(300000).fadeIn(0);
});
```

Todas las clases son `.intimeX` donde X es un número y el `delay` es de 1000 veces ese número, entonces esto se podría simplificar así:

```
$(function() {
    // para todos los elementos que contengan intime en su clase
    $("[class*=intime]").each(function() {
        // usar expresiones regulares para obtener el número detras de intime
        var retraso = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/intime\d+/g)[0].replace("intime",""));
        // mostrar el elemento con el retraso adecuado
        $(this).delay(retraso * 1000).fadeIn(0);
    });
});
```

**2. Outtime**

Los outtimes funcionarán de manera similar a los intimes, sólo que en lugar de buscar por intime, buscaremos outtime, y en lugar de hacer un fadeIn se hará un fadeOut.

Éste es tu código:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.outtime30').fadeOut(0);
}, 30000); 
setInterval(function() {
    $('.outtime34').fadeOut(0);
}, 34000);
setInterval(function() {
    $('.outtime40').fadeOut(0);
}, 40000);
```

Mismo procedimiento: todos tienen la clase outtimeX donde X es un número y el fadeOut se realiza X segundos después (el número * 1000). Aplicamos el mismo procedimiento:

```
$(function() {
    // para todos los elementos que contengan outtime en su clase
    $("[class*=outtime]").each(function() {
        // usar expresiones regulares para obtener el número detras de outtime
        var retraso = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/outtime\d+/g)[0].replace("outtime",""));
        // esconder el elemento usando el intervalo indicado
        setInterval("$('.outtime" + retraso + "').fadeOut(0)", retraso * 1000);
    });
});
```

**3. pre**

Esta parte es más complicada, aunque tampoco mucho. Voy a poner aquí el código que tienes, pero lo voy a formatear de manera diferente (aparte de corregir un par de cosillas):

```
jQuery(function () {
  var $els = $('pre[id^=pictureY5]'),
      i = 0,
      len = $els.length;

  $els.slice(1).hide();
  setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
      i = (i + 1) % len
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
  }, 300)
});
jQuery(function () {
  var $els = $('pre[id^=pictureX2]'),
      i = 0,
      len = $els.length;

  $els.slice(1).hide();
  setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
      i = (i + 1) % len
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0)
    }, 200);
  });
});
```

El código es similar en ambos casos, lo único que cambia de uno a otro son: los selectores (en uno es pictureY5 y en el otro es pictureX2) y los tiempos (300 y 200 respectivamente). Podrías intentar seleccionar ambos con jQuery (se puede hacer separando los selectores con coma), pero eso crearía problemas a la hora de mostrar/esconder los elementos (porque habría una única lista en lugar de dos listas).

Lo que haría para solucionar eso crear una función independiente a la que le pases como parámetros los dos valores que cambian. Entonces cuando se carga la página, hacer dos llamadas a la función, una para pictureY5 con 300 y otra para pictureX2 con 200.

Así podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
function mostrarEsconder(selector, tiempo) {
  var $els = $('pre[id^=' + selector + ']'),
      i = 0,
      len = $els.length;

  $els.slice(1).hide();
  setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
      i = (i + 1) % len;
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
  }, tiempo)
}

jQuery(function() {
    mostrarEsconder('pictureY5', 300);
    mostrarEsconder('pictureX2', 200);
});
```

---

Juntándolo todo, el código se vería reducido a algo así:

```
function mostrarEsconder(selector, tiempo) {
  var $els = $('pre[id^=' + selector + ']'),
      i = 0,
      len = $els.length;

  $els.slice(1).hide();
  setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
      i = (i + 1) % len;
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
  }, tiempo)
}

$(function() {

    $("[class*=intime]").each(function() {
        var retraso = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/intime\d+/g)[0].replace("intime",""));
        $(this).delay(retraso * 1000).fadeIn(0);
    });

    $("[class*=outtime]").each(function() {
        var retraso = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/outtime\d+/g)[0].replace("outtime",""));
        setInterval("$('.outtime" + retraso + "').fadeOut(0)", retraso * 1000);
    });

    mostrarEsconder('pictureY5', 300);
    mostrarEsconder('pictureX2', 200);

});
```

Comment: IMPRESIONANTE @alvaromontoro ojalá pudiese darte más puntos positivos!!

Comment: Una cosa @alvaromontoro en el Outtime hay un error que no consigo desentrañar con mis conocimientos que hace que no funcione (creo que es un error de escritura)

Comment: @IvanSoler fallo mío. Había hecho un copia-pega del intime y se me olvido cambiar "intime" por "outtime" en un sitio. Ya he corregido el fallo y ahora debería funcionar bien

Comment: Sí @alvaromontoro confirmado! Gran respuesta.